# Converting JSON to nested dictionary(python)

Tags: python, json

**I have a json object like this:**

```
{

parser_config:

[{"element_name": "jobs","type": "class", "attributes": ["title is-5", "company", "location"]},

{"element_name": "page-details","type":"class","attributes":["subtitle is-3", "title is-1"]}]

}
```

**I want to create a nested dictionary out of the attributes like this:**

```
{"jobs": {"class": "title is-5", "class_2": "location", "class_3": "company"},

 "page-details": {"class": "subtitle is-3", "class_2": "title is-1"}}
```

I have created a function like this:

```
def AttributeConstructor(json_data: dict, attribute_type: str) -> dict:
specific_attributes = []
config_data = json_data['parser_config']
for i in range(len(config_data)):
    for target in config_data[i]['attributes']:
        target_type = config_data[i]['type']
        if target_type == attribute_type:
            element_name = config_data[i]['element_name']
            specific_attributes.append(
                {element_name: {target_type: target}})
return specific_attributes
```

I am not sure how to get the desired output of keeping 1 element name for all {target_type: target}. I am setting attribute_type to "class".

The goal is to convert the JSON into a nested dictionary using a function, I cannot seem to get my function to output everything so I am left with:

```
{"jobs": {"class": "company"},

 "page-details": {"class": "title is-1"}}
```

instead of the whole nested dictionary. I also would like this to work on much larger JSON objects.

Comment: Trying to use an object with variable property names (`class`, `class_2` etc.) will cause you a lot of grief. Why not just use an array e.g. `{"jobs": {"class": ["title is-5", "company", "location"]}, ...}` and you could even just get rid of the nested object and just have `{"jobs":  ["title is-5", "company", "location"], "page-details": ["subtitle is-3", "title is-1"] }`

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: @Nick Good point, I will definitely give the output structure some more thought.

Answer (score 1):

You only add singelton dictionaries `{element_name: {target_type: target}}` to the list.

You could try

```
def attribute_constructor(json_data, attribute_type):
    return [
        {rec["element_name"]: {
            rec["type"] if i == 1 else f'{rec["type"]}_{i}': attr
            for i, attr in enumerate(rec["attributes"], start=1)}}
        for rec in json_data['parser_config'] if rec["type"] == attribute_type
    ]
```

or more closer to your attempt

```
def attribute_constructor(json_data, attribute_type):
    specific_attributes = []
    for rec in json_data['parser_config']:
        target_type = rec["type"]
        if target_type != attribute_type:
            continue
        specific_attributes.append(
            {rec["element_name"]: {
                target_type if i == 1 else f'{target_type}_{i}': attr
                for i, attr in enumerate(rec["attributes"], start=1)}}                
        )
    return specific_attributes
```

instead.

Result for

```
json_data = {
    "parser_config": [
        {"element_name": "jobs", "type": "class", "attributes": ["title is-5", "company", "location"]},
        {"element_name": "page-details", "type": "class","attributes": ["subtitle is-3", "title is-1"]}
    ]
}
print(attribute_constructor(json_data, "class"))
```

is

```
[{'jobs': {'class': 'title is-5', 'class_2': 'company', 'class_3': 'location'}},
 {'page-details': {'class': 'subtitle is-3', 'class_2': 'title is-1'}}]
```